# How can i extend an elastic search date range histogram aggregation query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I have an elastic search index named mep-report.

Each document has a status field. The possible values for status fields are "ENROUTE", "SUBMITTED", "DELIVERED", "FAILED" . Below is  the sample elastic search index with 6 documents.

```
{
  "took" : 10,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 13,
    "successful" : 13,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1094313,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "mep-reports-2019.09.11",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "68e8e03f-baf8-4bfc-a920-58e26edf835c-353899837500",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "status" : "ENROUTE",
          "@timestamp" : "2019-09-11T10:21:26.000Z"
        },
       {
        "_index" : "mep-reports-2019.09.11",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "68e8e03f-baf8-4bfc-a920-58e26edf835c-353899837501",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "status" : "ENROUTE",
          "@timestamp" : "2019-09-11T10:21:26.000Z"
        },
      {
        "_index" : "mep-reports-2019.09.11",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "68e8e03f-baf8-4bfc-a920-58e26edf835c-353899837502",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "status" : "SUBMITTED",
          "@timestamp" : "2019-09-11T10:21:26.000Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "mep-reports-2019.09.11",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "68e8e03f-baf8-4bfc-a920-58e26edf835c-353899837503",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "status" : "DELIVERED",
          "@timestamp" : "2019-09-11T10:21:26.000Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "mep-reports-2019.09.11",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "68e8e03f-baf8-4bfc-a920-58e26edf835c-353899837504",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "status" : "FAILED",
          "@timestamp" : "2019-09-11T10:21:26.000Z"
        },
      {
        "_index" : "mep-reports-2019.09.11",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "68e8e03f-baf8-4bfc-a920-58e26edf835c-353899837504",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "status" : "FAILED",
          "@timestamp" : "2019-09-11T10:21:26.000Z"
        }
      }
}
```

I would like to find an aggregation histogram distribution something like to get messages_processed, message_delivered,messages_failed .

```
messages_processed : 3 ( 2 documents in status ENROUTE + 1 Document with status SUBMITTED ) 
message_delivered  1  ( 1 document with status DELIVERED )
messages_failed : 2   ( 2 documents with status FAILED ) 

{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 13,
    "successful" : 13,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 21300,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "performance_over_time" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-02-21",
          "key" : 1582243200000,
          "doc_count" : 6,
          "message_processed": 3,
          "message_delivered": 1,
          "message_failed": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

So the following is my current query  and i would like to modify it to get some additional statistics such as message_processed , message_delivered, message_failed.  kindly let me know .


{ "size": 0, "query": { "bool": { "must": [ { "range": { "@timestamp": { "from": "2020-02-21T00:00Z", "to": "2020-02-21T23:59:59.999Z", "include_lower": true, "include_upper": true, "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ ||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ", "boost": 1.0 } } } ], "adjust_pure_negative": true, "boost": 1.0 } }, "aggregations": { "performance_over_time": { "date_histogram": { "field": "@timestamp", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "interval": "1d", "offset": 0, "order": { "_key": "asc" }, "keyed": false, "min_doc_count": 0 } } } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there with the query, you just need to add [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and looking at your request, I've come up with a [Scripted Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script).

I've also modified the [date histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) aggregation field `interval` to `calendar_interval` so that you get the values as per the calendar date.

### Query Request:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
  "size": 0,
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
         "range":{
            "@timestamp":{
               "from":"2019-09-10",
               "to":"2019-09-12",
               "include_lower":true,
               "include_upper":true,
               "boost":1.0
            }
         }
      }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative":true,
      "boost":1.0
    }
  },
  "aggs":{
    "message_processed":{
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "1d"                       <----- Note this
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_messages": {
          "terms": {
            "script": {                                 <----- Core Logic of Terms Agg
              "source": """
                if(doc['status'].value=="ENROUTE" || doc['status'].value == "SUBMITTED"){
                  return "message_processed";
                }else if(doc['status'].value=="DELIVERED"){
                  return "message_delivered"
                }else {
                  return "message_failed"
                }
                """,
              "lang": "painless"
            }, 
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the core logic what you are looking for is inside the scripted terms aggregation. Logic is self explainable if you go through it. Feel free to modify the logic that fits you.

For the sample date you've shared, you would get the result in the below format:

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 144,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 6,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "message_processed" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2019-09-11T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1568160000000,
          "doc_count" : 6,
          "my_messages" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "message_processed",
                "doc_count" : 3
              },
              {
                "key" : "message_failed",
                "doc_count" : 2
              },
              {
                "key" : "message_delivered",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```